# Compare date if there is a date in the database

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a simple LINQ query. I would like to only check the DateDisable if there is an entry in the database.  If the user doesn't select a date to disable the entry will always show. Can someone please show me how to add a conditional statement within linq

```
return (from promo in context.Promoes
        where promo.DateEnable <= DateTime.Today
        where promo.DateDisable >= DateTime.Today
        orderby promo.SortOrder
        select promo).ToList();
```

Comment: Is `DateDisable` a `DateTime?`?  If so, then isn't it just a matter of checking `where promo.DateDisable != null`?

Comment: it is nullable, if the value is there then I do want to check it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Given that `DateEnable` is a `DateTime?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190276/c-sharp-linq-compare-date-if-there-is-a-date-in-the-database#comment14686913_11190276), you can do the following:

```
// Get today.
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

return (
    from promo in context.Promoes
    where 
        promo.DateEnable <= today &&
        (promo.DateDisable == null || promo.DateDisable >= today)
    orderby promo.SortOrder
    select promo
).ToList();
```

Basically, you need to check for `null` *or* whether or not the date is greater than today.

Also you should capture the value outside of the statement, it's not guaranteed that the the LINQ provider will translate [`DateTime.Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) on the database side correctly.

However, be warned that because of deferred execution, if you wait a long time to execute the query, `today` might not give you the value you expect (if the time between declaring the query and executing it rolls past midnight).

Of course, if your database server is in a different timezone than your application server, then you'll need to ensure that `DateTime.Today` is handled by your LINQ provider correctly (so that it's executed on the server) and use that if you want to compare against time on the DB server.  If your provider *doesn't* handle translating `DateTime.Today` correctly, then you'll have to resort to a stored procedure and call that.